# How to iterate this multi dimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have got this very difficult array to iterate. I want value of only `name` index. I have tried a lot but not sure how to find this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [created_time] => DateTime Object 
( [date] => 2017-04-01 12:58:25.000000 [timezone_type] => 1 [timezone] =>
+00:00 ) [from] => Array ( [name] => Ghulam Mohe Ud Din [id] => 
1242172779233884 ) [message] => Hi there[id] => 10154774339307663_10154774534942663 ))
```

Here is my some practice of code:

```
foreach ($getPostlikes as $key=> $item) {//suppose array is $getPostlikes 


    foreach($item as $i)
    {
        echo $i['name'];
    }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is not a complex array. It's all a matter of organizing the data for yourself (and us?). Clearly the name is a part of an array inside the `from` value. You have to take that into account.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware. This is dynamic array. I can't change it by my self manually. I have to iterate it dynamically

Comment: Are you reacting to what I said? In that case I don't understand it. Do you mean you don't know the structure of the array at all?

Comment: Actually I am getting this array from facebook graph api php sdk. Now I want only name value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($getPostlikes as $key=> $item) {//suppose array is $getPostlikes 
  echo $item['from']['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you vary much

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [created_time] => DateTime Object,
        (
            [date] => 2017-04-01 12:58:25.000000, 
            [timezone_type] => 1, 
            [timezone] => +00:00),
        [from] => Array ( [name] => Ghulam Mohe Ud Din [id] => 1242172779233884 ),
        [message] => Hi there[id] => 10154774339307663_10154774534942663 )
    )
```

This will also eliminate duplicate names (each name will display only once).

```
$name_list = array();
foreach($postGetLikes as $postno => $post) {
    if(!isset($name_list[$post['from']['name']])) {
        $name_list[$post['from']['name']] = 0;
    }
    $name_list[$post['from']['name']]++;
}

foreach($name_list as $name => $count) {
    echo $name;
}
```